# Can I use Custom Claims to set a flag called 'disabled'?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When I register new users, can I use custom claims to set a flag for the created user? For ex. I want to set flag 'disabled' to False when the user is enabled and
to True when I block him.

I have read in many places people saying "*don't save other information rather than user role in Custom claims*" but why wouldn't it be a good idea to set this flag in Custom Claims? I understand Custom Claims doesn't hold much data but a flag wouldn't be a problem I guess.
I don't see anything wrong with it. Can someone help me out with a clarification?

Comment: You can save any data you want, there are a few recommendations, but you could have this flag false by default and chsnge it with whatever business logic when you request the custom claim... be aware that if you need to disable it in real time it wont work.

Comment: @andresmijares what can I use for real-time then?

Comment: Why do you want to use security rules for this?  Just because you *can*, it doesn't mean that you *should*.  Unless you define the specific use cases for this flag, it's hard to say if what you're doing makes sense.  Please edit the question to be more specific about the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am trying to implement "block/unblock" a user. I found out that `auth().createUser()` has `disabled` as property but I am using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` because the first one is not supported in React-Native I guess. So how can I actually set a flag which serves as an identification to tell if user is blocked or active?

Comment: How are you going to check and enforce it? Are you just expecting to write application code to access this field?

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry I didnt get that. I am just trying to learn how to Disable a user and Enable. How can I do that?

Comment: If you're changing the question, please edit the original to say what you mean, or close this one and start a new one.  Be sure to explain fully what you're trying to implement.

Comment: @DougStevenson the question is still the same tho. Simply put, how can I enable/disable user?

Comment: I think you're making an assumption about what it means for a user to be "disabled".  Firebase Auth doesn't assign any functionality to custom claims at all.  It is just a blob of JSON that you can attach to the user account. It doesn't **do** anything.  Setting custom claims will not "disable" a user, unless you have a very clear definition of **what a disabled user is, what they are supposed to be able to do**, and you're implementing security rules or some other specific code for that.

Comment: In the absence of your definition of what a "disabled" user actually is or can do, there's no specific advice anyone can give you.  Your question will have to be clear about what you're trying to implement.  Note that the Firebase Auth product already has a definition of "disabled", and it has nothing to do with custom claims. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/kajtgam-49Q